# 'package:flutter/src/widgets/widget_inspector.dart': Failed assertion: line 894 pos 16: 'index == parameters.length': is not true

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-dependencies

[image: Image one]

I get following weird exception thrown on my console after I upgraded my flutter version: 1.24.0-2.0.pre.98 yesterday. However the results are desired. Sometimes while scrolling in the application this exception is thrown as well. Can anyone please help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. After googling a lot here what I found and fixed my problem:

You are going to upgrade to the latest master:
1- flutter channel master
2- flutter upgrade --force
And run the app again :)

Comment: Yeah that must have worked. I just changed my channel from master to dev and ran flutter upgrade, that resolved my issue anyway. Thanks for the valuable feedback by the way.